# Symfony2 and multiple where

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I want to build a query using `where` with multiple values. Number of values is variable (from one to ten). My query looks like this for now:

```
return $repository->createQueryBuilder('s')
    ->where('s.id = :id')
    ->setParameter('id', '1')
```

But I want that `id` parameter to be array. I tried `setParameters`, but that's not the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
return $repository->createQueryBuilder('s')
   ->where('s.id IN (:id)')
   ->setParameter('id', array('1','2','3'))
```

This uses the array passed as a parameter to be using in the IN statment.

To use a variable do this :

```
$myarray = array('1','2','3');
return $repository->createQueryBuilder('s')
   ->where('s.id IN (:id)')
   ->setParameter('id', $myarray)
```

Comment: Okay, works great! Can you tell me also, how can I pass an variable instead of array? When I define `$asd` variable outside the builder, and then I want to use it, Symfony returns unknown variable.

Comment: Yeah, and I was in the form builder :) So I had to use `use`. But nevertheless, your answer helped me A LOT. Thanks!